# Why wouldn't html content match a fairly simple regex?

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm having html page content as a string and trying to check if it matches regexp of `^.+$`. And it returns false. Can't get why it does so.

Code is fairly simple:

```
content.matches(regexp)
```

Comment: Please show the exact code that is being used, in addition an example of the HTML that isn't matching.

Comment: @vcsjones, there's no need to post input: if `^.+$` doesn't match, it's either an empty string, or it contains a `\r` or `\n`. In all other cases, the regex would match (`matches("^.+$")` would return `true`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `.` does not match `\r` and `\n`. To let `.` also match them, enable DOT-ALL (the `s` flag):

```
^(?s).+$
```

Comment: I thought it had something to do with that! :) Thanks!